# Why doesn't my variable value get passed to the finally block in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, httplib

This is for python 2.7.10
Perhaps I'm not using the try..except..finally block correctly.

I need to check on the HTTP response code I get from a webpage.
If I get a 200 code, everything is working.  If I get any other code, report what code.

It works fine if I get a 200 HTTP code.
If I get an exception, for some reason, it gives me an UnboundedLocalError, stating my variable isn't referenced.  How do I get my variable to be recognized in the finally block?

Here's my code:

```
try:
   conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host, port=9000)
   conn.request("GET", "/alive")
   resp = conn.getresponse().status
except Exception as e:
   print "got some exception"
   print "exception " + e 
   print "Exception msg: " + e.message
   print "Args for exception: " + e.args
finally:
   if resp == 200:
      print "got a 200 http response.  everything seems good"
   if resp != 200:
      print "didn't get a 200 http response.  something wrong"
   print "this is the code we got: " + str(resp)
```

This is the output we get if it works with a http 200 code:

```
got a 200 http response.  everything seems good this is the code we got: 200
```

This is the output we get if it gets an exception

```
got some exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "monitorAlive.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "monitorAlive.py", line 24, in main
    get_status_code(host)
  File "monitorAlive.py", line 16, in get_status_code
    if resp == 200:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'resp' referenced before assignment
```

Edit: If I wait like 5 min, and hit the website with a problem, then I get the response code / proper output.  There might be a second question here as to why the website is taking so long to return the http 500 code (5 min to work).

Comment: As an aside, `else:` would suffice in place of `if resp != 200:`

Comment: Something doesn't look right. The error only shows the output for the first of the 4 `print` statements in the `except` block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If an exception happens, then the assignment statement (`resp = conn.getresponse().status`) either never runs or never finishes.<sup>1</sup>  In that case, when the `finally` clause runs, you'll get an error because `resp` was never set to anything.

Based on the usage, it *looks* to me like you want to use `else` instead of `finally`.  `finally` will run no matter what, but `else` will only run if the `try` suite finished without an exception.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Consider an exception that happens in `conn.getresponse` -- Since an exception was raised, `conn.getresponse` never *returns* anything so there is no value to be bound to the `resp` on the left hand side.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The solution is assign None to "resp" before "try" clause.Like this below.

```
resp = None
try:
```

When you run conn.request("GET", "/alive"), this may cause an Exception if timeout,then your code will enter "except" and then "finally" clause.But the variable haven't assigned,so it goes wrong.