# Taking a while for website to return 500 Internal server error

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, playframework, httplib

This is a followup question to [my other question here on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38258519/why-doesnt-my-variable-value-get-passed-to-the-finally-block-in-python/).

Not sure if this is a problem with play or this is normal results for a webserver.  I am using play 2.1.2

I have a website that immediately returns http code 200 if things are working fine.
If the site has problems, for some reason, it doesn't immediately return a 500 Internal Server Error.  It seems like it will take 5 min for it to finally return a 500 error.

Is this a problem with using the play framework to run our site or is there something else I should check as to why this is happening?  I'm also using httplib from python to check the website.

I don't know what other details to add to help debug but hopefully the simple answer is the play framework is doing something to the site and doesn't reply with a 500 code until the time out (5 min) has passed.

UPDATE: Attached is the message from the server when I hit it with my script.  This is on a test server so I'm expecting it to fail.  I executed `ulimit -n 275` to cause an out of files error on the server.

This is the error I get from my script if I run it within 5 min of causing a problem:

> ```
> got some exception
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "monitorAlive.py", line 27, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "monitorAlive.py", line 24, in main
>     get_status_code(host)
>   File "monitorAlive.py", line 16, in get_status_code
>     if resp == 200:
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'resp' referenced before assignment
> ```

However, if I wait 5+ min and then I run my script to check on the site, this is what I get:

> ```
> didn't get a 200 http response.  something wrong
> this is the code we got: 500
> ```

These are the log msgs at the time I caused the out of file error.  My script doesn't cause the webserver to record any additional messages but I run my script after I purposely cause the site/server to have problems so these msgs are from me causing an out of files error.

```
! @70jo4chan - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.PlayException: Not initialized[?]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:92) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:273) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:272) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$.mainDev(NettyServer.scala:271) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
        at play.core.server.NettyServer.mainDev(NettyServer.scala) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
        at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$53$$anonfun$55.apply(PlayCommands.scala:575) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$53$$anonfun$55.apply(PlayCommands.scala:507) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Either$RightProjection.map(Either.scala:533) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$53.apply(PlayCommands.scala:507) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$53.apply(PlayCommands.scala:487) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$sbt$Command$$apply1$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Command.scala:72) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:90) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.State$$anon$2.process(State.scala:170) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:71) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:64) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:53) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:50) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:50) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:33) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:17) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:13) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:26) ~[na:na]
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:55) ~[na:na]
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45) ~[na:na]
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:69) ~[na:na]
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16) ~[na:na]
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31) ~[na:na]
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20) ~[na:na]
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala) ~[na:na]
```

UPDATE #2: Forgot to mention I'm using play 2.1.2

Comment: Do you have access to server logs?

Comment: @rethab, thx for looking.  i've added them to the question as an edit, although, it doesn't tell us much  =(

Comment: @rethab Are you running Play in dev mode? Maybe it is just compiling things?

Comment: @Salem, thx for looking.  I don't think I am.  I typed "play run" and the server ran.

Comment: @Classified `run` starts the app in dev mode (more info [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Production)). Try to run `play compile` and then `play start` and check if you still get the same error. Also you may want to add the play version you are using

Comment: @salem, thx for your advice.  i still don't get what I'm looking for but at least the behavior above doesn't occur anymore.  if you make your comment into an answer, I can upvote/accept. thx again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `play run`, your app will be started in dev mode. In this mode , the app itself will only really start when it gets the first request. Sometimes it happens that, even after the server is started and should be ready to accept requests, Play detects that something has changed and recompiles some things, leaving the browser "waiting" (I have noticed this behaviour in every Play 2.x version, but I'm not sure if it is something related to my setup or a bug). This can be the reason of those delays you are getting.

The best way to avoid this is to make sure everything is ready, using `play copile` and `play start`, or using `play dist`, which will provide you a file with your application ready to be used in production. See [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/Production) for more information.